# Webpack retain folder structure on dist folder

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have the following `src` folder structure (may change):

```
- src/
  - vue/
    - classes/
    - components/
      -inputs/
```

That is just an example. The `src` folder may have `x` inner folders and recursively.

I need to write a webpack code that outputs the exact same folder structure to a folder prefix `dist` without knowing beforehand what is the folder structure (the code should be automatic).

This is what I tried:

```js
var compiler = function(sourcePath, buildPath) {
    return {
        entry: glob.sync(sourcePath).reduce((files, file, index) => {
            const filename = file.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '').replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, "")
            Allfiles[filename] = file

            Allfiles = Object.assign({}, Allfiles);
    
            return Allfiles
        }),

        output: {
            path: buildPath,
            filename: '[name].js',
        },
        
        ...
}

module.exports [
   ...,
   compiler(path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/vue/**/*.js'), path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')),
]
```

It works for the entry point (find all files recursively and operates on them), however the output is always on dist without any folder structure (all files are on the same path `/dist`, but I need it to be `/dist/vue`, `/dist/vue/components`, etc).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Put the variable "Allfiles" inside the function

if you're using node ^12+ change the "filename" to "chunkFilename"

and try this fuction on  output

```
output: {
        path: buildPath,
        filename: function(pathData) {
            var src = new RegExp("[^*]*")
                .exec(sourcePath)[0]
                .replace(/\\/g, "/");

            return pathData.chunk.entryModule.rawRequest.replace(src, "");
        }
    },
```

Comment: if you're using node ^12+ change the "filename" to "chunkFilename"